# NodeRed: How to get reply from Slack app interactive message

Tags: node.js, slack, node-red

I'm trying to make it so that NodeRed uses a webhook to send an interactive message to a slack app to ask permission to activate something. I can POST to the webhook without any issues from my custom node, but how do I get the reply?

Do I need to use the "http in" node to create an endpoint Slack can use? Is there a way to handle it from the same node that POSTs the message?

Also, I'm running NodeRed locally. Can I use ngrok so that Slack can access the http endpoint (in case I need to use that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own http endpoints that are private to your custom node, this is how nodes that need to do oAuth handle the callback. Also nodes like the serial port node do this to supply information to the config dialog.

Make sure to give the endpoint a unique route so it's unlikely to clash with any other nodes.

You can look at the source for the serial port node [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/io/serialport/25-serial.js#L291)

How you ensure that Node-RED is safely made accessible from the internet should be a separate question.

Comment: Taking that example, how would I call that endpoint? Place a get to localhost:1880/serialports (or ngrok-link-here/serialports)?

Comment: yes, assuming you've not changed the admin route in the settings.js then it would be "http://hostname:1880/serialports"

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, ngrok works nicely for exposing your local webserver securely to the Internet and Slack. I use it every day for my Slack app development. Keep in mind that if your app can't be reached from the Internet, then also Slack can not reach it.

2) Interactive Messages only work with [Slack apps](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps). One reason being that you need to provide the route to your app, so that Slack knows where to send the requests when someone uses your interactive messages (e.g. clicks on a button). But you can use interactive messages with webhooks, as long as both are setup within the same Slack app.

3) Don't believe the "http-in node" approach will work. As said, you need to configure the route to your app for receiving messages from Slack in your Slack appp.